# Why does the correlation function of this stochastic differential equation starts at different points?

Tags: python, computational-physics, numerics, statistics, differential-equations

I am working with the following differential equation:

The equation is $$x=\beta +\sqrt{2D} \xi(t)$$ where $\xi(t)$ is a white noise term, with a reflecting wall boundary conditions.

After solving the equation numerically with Euler-Maruyama method, I used the Wiener-Khinchin theorem  (Using FFT) to find a numerical solution for the correlation function. 
My problem is, get every time a new starting point for the correlation function even for exactly the same parameters, no matter how I change the parameters, and I am sure of my code because I have tried it on Orstein-Uhlenbeck and the results were right.

What is the problem of the varying starting points, or what did I misunderstand about correlation functions that is leading to this  ?? (Please see the code below, and the plots of the correlation function for the same given parameters)
[image: Correlation function of the SDE]
[image: Another correlation function for the same SDE with exactly the same parameteres]
[image: another example of the same simulation of the correlation function]

This is the code for simulating the SDE with Euler method and simulating the correlation function

```
 N = 8192
dt = 0.3
T = N*dt
time = np.arange(N)*dt
gamma = 0.1
D=1
v_factor = math.sqrt(2*D*dt)
v_data = []

v=1

###Eurler method to solve the SDE
for t in range(50000):  ##This part just to make sure we get the stationary process
        F = random.gauss(0,1)
        v = v - gamma*dt + v_factor*F
        if v<0:
            v=-v
for t in range(N):
        F = random.gauss(0,1)
        v = v - gamma*dt + v_factor*F
        if v<0:
            v=-v
        v_data.append(v)
# Compute numerically the autocorrelation via a Fourier transform

fft_cor = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(v_data, v_data[::-1])[N-1:]
fft_cor /= (N - np.arange(N))
plt.plot(time, fft_cor, 'k-', lw=2,label="Fourier-Transform")


# Compute the autocorrelation via the Wiener-Khinchin theorem

psd = np.fft.fft(v_data)*np.conj(np.fft.fft(v_data))/N
C = np.fft.ifft(psd).real

plt.plot(time, C,label='Wiener-Khinchin theorem')
```